# What is this schematic symbol with intersecting triangles?

Tags: identification, schematics, atmega, symbol

[image]

What is this symbol?  I think it is some kind of amplifier or buffer, but I was unable find any information using search terms like "overlapping triangles," "intersecting triangles," or "double triangle symbol."

For context, I came across it in the [ATmega2560 datasheet (pdf)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf), in Figure 13-2 on page 68, reproduced below:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/158243/1743

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a MOS [pass/transmission gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate).

Comment: Just want to point out that "Bow tie" seems to be the search name that OP missed for that symbol.